# In Django, how to restrict some url access depending on users' groups?

Tags: django

In my Django application, I have 3 types of roles(groups)

Superuser
AccountAdmin
ShopAdmin

I want that, superuser can access to every url, but other 2 admins cannot access /su/* urls.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
def your_su_view(request):
    pass
```

Comment: But I need something like user.is_ingroup("ShopAdmin")

Comment: @Burak Why? You need to make sure no one except superuser can access your su views, right? That's what my solution do.

Comment: Below code from [link][1] solved my issue. Also thank you very much DrTyrsa, you showed me the way:)


    from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required,user_passes_test
    
    @login_required
    @user_passes_test(lambda u: u.groups.filter(name='Student').count() == 0, login_url='/myapp/denied/')

     def some_view(request):


  [1]: http://bradmontgomery.net/blog/restricting-access-by-group-in-django/

Comment: @Burak It will work too, but it requires one extra DB hit on every request. And my solution doesn't. Django has two built-in "groups": `user.is_superuser` and `user.is_staff`, you have special reasons not to use them in your case?

Comment: Yes, it would work for this case. But let's say ShopAdmin can see /shop/ url, AccountAdmin can see /account/ url, and SuperUser can see each urls. So I need a more flexible solution.

Comment: Excellent! In addition, as per link[1] above, it is compatible with `@login_required`, which was a requirement for me.